# What is the correct syntax when using foreach and mysqli_fetch_all

Tags: php, mysqli, foreach, fetchall

As part of another problem I need to use `mysqli_fetch_all` (which I am told creates an array). I have never used it before and can not find solutions on the Internet that I can understand. I am trying to get this to list the keys and values of the array I create with `mysqli_fetch_all`. Once I can list them I can access them and use them as part of a more complicated code. I can print the array, but not get to the keys or values in `foreach` so unless there are two different types of array it seems a tricky one.

```
$q5 = 'SELECT * FROM cities ORDER BY cityname';
$mytable5 = mysqli_query($conned, $q5);
$row5 = mysqli_fetch_all($mytable5, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
print_r($row5);
echo "<br><br>";
foreach ($row5 as $key => $value) {
    print "Key = " . $key . ". Value = " . $value . ".<br><br>";
}
```

This is the output:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [countryid4city] => 44 [cityname] => Chelsea ) [1] => Array ( [countryid4city] => 44 [cityname] => Clapham ) [2] => Array ( [countryid4city] => 46 [cityname] => Lidingö ) [3] => Array ( [countryid4city] => 44 [cityname] => London ) [4] => Array ( [countryid4city] => 1 [cityname] => New York ) [5] => Array ( [countryid4city] => 1 [cityname] => San Francisco ) [6] => Array ( [countryid4city] => 46 [cityname] => Stockholm ) )
>
> Key = 0. Value = Array.
>
> Key = 1. Value = Array.
>
> Key = 2. Value = Array.
>
> Key = 3. Value = Array.
>
> Key = 4. Value = Array.
>
> Key = 5. Value = Array.
>
> Key = 6. Value = Array.

Comment: The more dimensions to an array, the more for each loops you have to use, ideally you would have a single level in the array i.e. one dimensional arrays. What you're doing is a right step but a right step in the wrong direction, try adjusting your code so as you get and store one dimensional arrays in your db

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_fetch_all` returns an array of arrays. You need another loop to iterate the 2 dimensions.

```
$q5 = 'SELECT * FROM cities ORDER BY cityname';
$mytable5 = mysqli_query($conned, $q5);
$results = mysqli_fetch_all($mytable5, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo "<br><br>";
foreach ($results as $row5) {
    foreach ($row5 as $key => $value) {
        print "Key = " . $key . ". Value = " . $value . ".<br><br>";
    }
}
```